# WebFlux + MongoDB + docker compose = error

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-webflux

I've got a problem with this integration. I use MongoDB based on docker without problems, but when I create a Docker Compose, the Spring Boot WebFlux stop to find the Mongo. I'm trying to find the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

The service log shows me this problem:

```
2021-08-05 14:04:45.184  INFO 1 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017 2021-08-05T14:04:45.203968373Z
```

My Spring Mongo config is:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(value = "br.com.person.repositories")
public class MongoReactiveConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private String port;


    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        final String connectionString = String.format("mongodb://%s:%s/%s", host, port, database);
        return MongoClients.create(connectionString);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return this.database;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() {
        return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
    }
}
```

Here's my docker-compose.ymlspri

```
version: "3.8"
  services:
  #####################
  ##### DATABASES #####
  #####################
  person_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: person_db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=person_database
    networks:
      - backend_network

  ######################
  #####   DevOps   #####
  ######################
  eureka_service:
    container_name: eureka_service
    image: eureka:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports: 
      - 8761:8761
    environment: 
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
    networks:
      - backend_network

  gateway_service:
    container_name: gateway_service
    image: gateway:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    depends_on: 
      - eureka_service
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    environment: 
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
    networks:
      - backend_network

  ######################
  #####  SERVICES  #####
  ######################
  person_service:
    container_name: person_service
    image: person:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    depends_on:
      - eureka_service
      - gateway_service
      - person_db
    ports:
      - 8180:8180
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=person_db
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=person_database
    networks:
      - backend_network

networks:
  backend_network:
  driver: bridge
```

When I run then docker compose, the person-service, shows this log

```
2021-08-05T14:04:31.598842495Z Setting Active Processor Count to 4
2021-08-05T14:04:31.819407236Z Calculating JVM memory based on 949096K available memory
2021-08-05T14:04:31.819861212Z Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx513855K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128040K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 949096K, Thread Count: 50, Loaded Class Count: 20192, Headroom: 0%)
2021-08-05T14:04:31.848459508Z Adding 129 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
2021-08-05T14:04:31.904569794Z Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
2021-08-05T14:04:31.912394489Z Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -agentpath:/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jvmkill/jvmkill-1.16.0-RELEASE.so=printHeapHistogram=1 -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=4 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx513855K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128040K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413180717Z 
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413211708Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413216318Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413320843Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413354057Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413765333Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-08-05T14:04:35.413782827Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-08-05T14:04:35.417621291Z  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.3)
2021-08-05T14:04:35.417654257Z 
2021-08-05T14:04:36.002780729Z     2021-08-05 14:04:35.999  INFO 1 --- [           main] br.com.fechaki.person.PersonApplication  : Starting PersonApplication using Java 11.0.12 on 58e28b490a76 with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
2021-08-05T14:04:36.011092592Z     2021-08-05 14:04:36.010  INFO 1 --- [           main] br.com.fechaki.person.PersonApplication  : The following profiles are active: prod
2021-08-05T14:04:40.365284181Z     2021-08-05 14:04:40.364  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-08-05T14:04:40.930071250Z     2021-08-05 14:04:40.929  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 546 ms. Found 4 Reactive MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-08-05T14:04:42.970647290Z     2021-08-05 14:04:42.969  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0802a2fe-6be5-304b-a881-d9075ba4ecbd
2021-08-05T14:04:43.452183684Z     2021-08-05 14:04:43.451  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-08-05T14:04:43.454250069Z     2021-08-05 14:04:43.453  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-08-05T14:04:43.459156593Z     2021-08-05 14:04:43.458  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reactorDeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-08-05T14:04:44.896692596Z     2021-08-05 14:04:44.896  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203933051Z     2021-08-05 14:04:45.184  INFO 1 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203968373Z 
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203973180Z com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203976425Z  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:124) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203979943Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203982885Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203985770Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203988692Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203991515Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203994830Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.203997655Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204000381Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204003321Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204006214Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204009012Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204011815Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204014689Z  ... 1 common frames omitted
2021-08-05T14:04:45.204017452Z 
2021-08-05T14:04:45.545976961Z     2021-08-05 14:04:45.545  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2021-08-05T14:04:45.703706515Z     2021-08-05 14:04:45.702  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2021-08-05T14:04:47.551565146Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.550  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[person-db:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-08-05T14:04:47.840405051Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.839  INFO 1 --- [person-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:2}] to person-db:27017
2021-08-05T14:04:47.843604229Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.839  INFO 1 --- [person-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:1}] to person-db:27017
2021-08-05T14:04:47.850063426Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.849  INFO 1 --- [person-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=person-db:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=233945852}
2021-08-05T14:04:50.033785035Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.033  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-08-05T14:04:50.506380131Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.505  INFO 1 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate.
2021-08-05T14:04:50.613620505Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.613  WARN 1 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2021-08-05T14:04:50.659847813Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.659  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2021-08-05T14:04:50.786660930Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.783  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2021-08-05T14:04:50.795473894Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.795  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2021-08-05T14:04:50.836725459Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2021-08-05T14:04:50.836793911Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2021-08-05T14:04:50.836957193Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2021-08-05T14:04:50.837273453Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2021-08-05T14:04:50.837776663Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.837  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2021-08-05T14:04:50.837921597Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.837  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2021-08-05T14:04:50.838032297Z     2021-08-05 14:04:50.837  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2021-08-05T14:04:51.845984898Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.845  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2021-08-05T14:04:51.850243611Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.849  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2021-08-05T14:04:51.855368679Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.854  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2021-08-05T14:04:51.865201633Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.864  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1628172291862 with initial instances count: 0
2021-08-05T14:04:51.867569693Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.867  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application PERSON-SERVICE with eureka with status UP
2021-08-05T14:04:51.869260578Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.868  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1628172291868, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2021-08-05T14:04:51.887066149Z     2021-08-05 14:04:51.886  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PERSON-SERVICE/58e28b490a76:person-service:8180: registering service...
2021-08-05T14:04:52.174876518Z     2021-08-05 14:04:52.174  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8180
2021-08-05T14:04:52.195632232Z     2021-08-05 14:04:52.195  INFO 1 --- [TaskExecutor-14] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8180
2021-08-05T14:04:52.243191280Z     2021-08-05 14:04:52.242  INFO 1 --- [           main] br.com.fechaki.person.PersonApplication  : Started PersonApplication in 18.647 seconds (JVM running for 20.352)
2021-08-05T14:04:52.314744592Z     2021-08-05 14:04:52.314  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PERSON-SERVICE/58e28b490a76:person-service:8180 - registration status: 204
2021-08-05T14:05:21.830865756Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.830  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2021-08-05T14:05:21.830998294Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.830  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2021-08-05T14:05:21.831012581Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.830  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2021-08-05T14:05:21.831109915Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.830  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2021-08-05T14:05:21.831234786Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.830  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2021-08-05T14:05:21.831492323Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.831  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
2021-08-05T14:05:21.831507822Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.831  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2021-08-05T14:05:21.854773386Z     2021-08-05 14:05:21.854  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days testing and testing again, I've found one problem with my **MongoReactiveConfig** class. I thought I did something wrong on it. reading the Spring documentation, I've found this note:

[image: Spring MongoDB Documentation Note]

To make it work, I removed my **MongoReactiveConfig** class and changed my docker-compose.yml config to change database, host, port spring parameters to URI.

Before:

```
  ######################
  #####  Services  #####
  ######################
  person-service:
    container_name: person-service
    image: person:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
      - gateway-service
    links:
      - person-db
    ports:
      - 8180:8180
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=person-db
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=person_database
```

After:

```
  ######################
  #####  Services  #####
  ######################
  person-service:
    container_name: person-service
    image: person:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
      - gateway-service
    links:
      - person-db
    ports:
      - 8180:8180
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://person-db:27017/person_database
```

I really don't know why it not shows the real error and try resolve it with localhost. Maybe on Spring, it should check Mongo Version before try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is the problem here? Without knowing more about the application, I can't really tell why it's trying `localhost` first, but it seems like it's able to connect to mongo running on the `person-db` container after that based on these logs:

```
2021-08-05T14:04:47.551565146Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.550  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[person-db:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-08-05T14:04:47.840405051Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.839  INFO 1 --- [person-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:2}] to person-db:27017
2021-08-05T14:04:47.843604229Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.839  INFO 1 --- [person-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:1}] to person-db:27017
2021-08-05T14:04:47.850063426Z     2021-08-05 14:04:47.849  INFO 1 --- [person-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=person-db:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=233945852}
```

Comment: The problem is that when I run the app, it's looking for [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster  and not for the person-db host on the docker compose. And it`s trying to run a cluster, and I don't defined one